# Function for extracting data from lists

Tags: python

I'm struggling with this problem:

Create a function named `get_data`, that takes two arguments, `Data` and `Key`.

- `Data` is the list of dictionaries in `list_1`
- `Key` are the data that I need to extract from the list of dictionaries `list_1`.
  This function should then return a list of these attributes.

Example 1:
Input:

```
get_data(list_1, “name”)
```

Output:

```
[“Jerome","Ibraheem","Tiana","Lucas","Rickie”]
```

Example 2:
Input:

```
get_data(list_1, “weight”)
```

Output:

```
[3.38,3.08,0.81,3.33,4.4]
```

I did the following code, but I get as output only the first line:

```
def main(list_1):
    return main
     
list_1 = [
               {'name': 'Jerome', 'weight': 3.38, 'wingspan': 49.96, 'length': 19.75},
               {'name': 'Ibraheem', 'weight': 3.08, 'wingspan': 50.59, 'length': 20.6},
               {'name': 'Tiana', 'weight': 0.81, 'wingspan': 47.86, 'length': 17.94},
               {'name': 'Lucas', 'weight': 3.33, 'wingspan': 48.27, 'length': 18.77},
               {'name': 'Rickie', 'weight': 4.4, 'wingspan': 51.0, 'length': 20.34}
         ]
     
def get_data(data,key):
    for key in data:
        return key
data = list_1
key = []
output = get_data(data,key)
print(output)
```

Comment: You can just use `return [d[key] for d in data]` in `get_data()`. Also your second param to `get_data()` differs from your sample and code

Comment: for x in list_1:
    print(x['name'],x['weight'])

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working code:

```
def get_data(data: dict, key: str):
    return [item[key] for item in data]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [
        {"name": "Jerome", "weight": 3.38, "wingspan": 49.96, "length": 19.75},
        {"name": "Ibraheem", "weight": 3.08, "wingspan": 50.59, "length": 20.6},
        {"name": "Tiana", "weight": 0.81, "wingspan": 47.86, "length": 17.94},
        {"name": "Lucas", "weight": 3.33, "wingspan": 48.27, "length": 18.77},
        {"name": "Rickie", "weight": 4.4, "wingspan": 51.0, "length": 20.34},
    ]

    output = get_data(data, "name")

    print(f"{output=}")
```

Comment: you got an extra `=` in the f string

Comment: I made it on purpose. With the equal sign, the name of the variable is also displayed by print.